# Retaining values after closing the R-shiny webapp

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

While developing a WebApp (some kind of calculator), I am stuck at a point where the WebApp needs to remember/retain  a couple inputs (not all) after closing the WebApp. The reason of this functioning is to be capable of comparing the previous inputs with the current ones.

I am able to retain the values for many runs until it is closed. The server code for the same is as follows:

```
 rv_count <- reactiveValues(prev_bins = NULL)  
 
  observeEvent(input$count, {
    
    rv_count$prev_bins <- c(rv_count$prev_bins, input$count)
  }) 
 
  output$menu_item_3_id_output <- renderPrint({
    
    cat(rv_count$prev_bins, sep = ', ')
  })
```

Is there any way the WebApp can display the previous `n` values as soon as it runs. A not very efficient way I can think of is saving the previous values followed by loading them as the app runs. But I am looking for something more exciting and interesting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the only way is what you've suggested. I cannot think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and decided to save/load my data in a google spreadsheet using the `googlesheets4` library. Works fine for me.

Comment: Could you please provide a smallest working example ?